# Inconsistent ERRORLEVEL inside a batch file

Tags: windows, windows-7

In a batch file, I have an inconsistent errorlevel behavior:

The following code always gives errorlevel 0 in one location (somewhere in the middle - exactly where i need it) inside the batch file.

I copied only this snippet and placed it in the beginning and at the end of the batch file. In those locations, the result is always 1.

Here is the code snippet:

dir c:\

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more

Any idea how to make it work also in the middle of the file? What am I doing wrong? I would hate to solve it with GOTOs(to the end of the file and back to where I need the result.)

Comment: The whole ping issue was unrelated to the errorlevel question, so I replaced it with a 'dir' command.

Comment: Please provide us with a code snippet that demonstrates fully the inconsistent behaviour

Answer (score 5):

%ERRORLEVEL% is not ERRORLEVEL

You are confusing the command interpreters ERRORLEVEL return value and the environment variable ERRORLEVEL. When a command runs it sets the ERRORLEVEL value not the environment variable value. You can interrogate the return value using the

```
IF ERRORLEVEL n
```

command which returns true if the ERRORLEVEL return value is n or higher e.g.

```
dir C:\

<directory listing omitted>

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more
```

would print nothing whereas

```
dir C:\somenonexistentdir

File Not Found

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more
ERRORLEVEL is 1 or more
```

the message is printed. My guess is that you are setting the value of %ERRORLEVEL% in your script and expecting later return values to overwrite this. As %ERRORLEVEL% is not ERRORLEVEL this doesn't happen.

Comment: dir c:\ set %errorlevel%  to 0

Comment: dir nonexistentdir set %errorlevel% to 1

Comment: What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't query %ERRORLEVEL% http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

Comment: OIC %ERRORLEVEL% was replaced as a fallback with error level

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information, however, the original problem still exists, with the inconsistent behavior of error level in the batch file, see the original description.

Comment: Thank you, but it is digressing from my original topis, which is the inconsistent behavior of error level.

Comment: @Doron, `dir c:\` will return a zero because the command exits successfully. `dir nonexistendir` will return non-zero because the command encountered an error (directory not found).